# What is the inverse of $f'(x)-f(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Consider the following function $P$ defined as
$P(f(x))=f'(x)-f(x)$

What is the inverse of $P$?

I can't figure this one out.
A hint would be very helpful.

Comment: Did you look at some examples?

Comment: What's the domain of $P$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito the domain of P is $C^1([a,b])$

Comment: So it is actually $P(f)=f'-f$ and we are looking for a functional $Q(P(f))=P(Q(f))=f$?

Comment: @Milten Well in an exercise I have I need to proof that the inverse of P is continuous. So I think it should be possible

Comment: P is not one-to-one.  For instance, both e^x and 2e^x are mapped to zero.  Is there any more information you’re leaving out?

Comment: @RobDukes I actually need to find the inverse of $P(f(x))=f'(x)-af(x)$ and $Q(f(x))=f'(x)+bf(x)$. But I didn't want somebody else to solve it for me. So I just gave something familiar. Where a and b are some constants in R

Comment: @MariusS.L. Yes you are right

Comment: @John.W $P$ and $Q$ are not invertible in these cases either, since their kernels are still nontrivial. Notice that $P\left(ce^{ax}\right)\equiv 0$ and $Q\left(ce^{-bx}\right)\equiv 0$ for any constant $c$.

Comment: @AlannRosas this is very strange, in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4275498/understanding-well-posedness/4275829?noredirect=1#comment8898190_4275829 is the exercise I am working on. Given the definitions there, inverting P (and Q) should be possible. Or am I misunderstanding something in general.

Comment: Use [these inversion formulas](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/InversionFormulas.html), more specific this time.

Comment: @TymaGaidash which of them?

Comment: You can often solve $P(f) = g$ using the integrating factor technique from ODEs.

Comment: @John.W Probably Lagrange Inversion or [Fourier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem). Note that the inverse has an interval of convergence and only has one branch of the inverse if the function fails the vertical line test. Or just do $$y=f’(x)-f(x)\mathop\implies^\text{inverse}x=f’(y)-f(y)$$ but these are hard to use sometimes.

Comment: So what you actually have is the differential operator $D$ and you are looking for $(D-a\mathbb{1})^{-1}.$ You could use a series expansion for that, but this looks very formal and convergence is another question.

Comment: $P\left(f(x)\right)=e^{x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x}\cdot f(x)\right)$, the antiderivatives are not unique

Comment: Also, please add a bit of context and detail as you [technically should](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 3):

While there is no inverse, you *can* find a right inverse. As Rezha Adrian Tanuharja points out, we have
$$\tag{$1$}
P(f(x)) = e^x\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x}f(x)\right).
$$
But then we can solve for $f$ to get
$$\tag{$2$}
f(x) = e^x \int e^{-x}P(f(x))\,dx,
$$
for some choice of antiderivative. More importantly, $(2)\Rightarrow(1)$ for any choice of antiderivative, which means that
$$
Q(g):= x \mapsto e^x \int_a^x e^{-t}g(t)\,dt
$$
satisfies $P(Q(g))=g$. Note that $Q$ is not a unique solution, since any antiderivative would have worked.

As many have noted, $P$ is not injective, so you can't find a well defined left inverse.